# How to enable more than 8 light sources in URP?

Tags: unity, rendering

My location in the scene is the Bunker, there are many light sources in the form of wall lamps. There are more than 8 of them. Therefore, you need to be able to render more than 8 lights in the scene. How to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: You may want to examine whether you can bake the light or otherwise approximate it. URP is designed for lower-spec hardware, on which higher numbers of simultaneous lights per object can become quite taxing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding more than 8 lights to the scene?

The 8 light limit is not about *only 8 lights allowed in scene*, it's *a mesh can only by affected by the nearest 8 lights*.

Take this as an example: let's suppose your bunker is one mesh, ok? So, you place 9 lights inside of it. The bunker, being one mesh, will only be affected by 8 of the 9 lights. The 9th light will only affect other meshes, since your bunker has already reached its limit.

One way to circumvent this would be to divide your bunker into several parts, as if it were a modular system. Each part can be affected by 8 different lights.

Another way would be to change the rendering path from Forward to Deferred. The latter is precisely for when you need more than 8 lights on scene.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/nwngcg/more_than_8_lights_in_urp/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/nhqilk/point_lights_in_urp_how_to_add_more_than_4/)